# Mathematical Olympiad Problem

Tags: analysis, functions, contest-math

Let $\Bbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers. Determine all functions $f:\Bbb{R}\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ satisfying the equation $$f(x+f(x+y))+f(xy) = x + f(x+y)+yf(x)$$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ does the job.

Comment: This is problem 5 from IMO 2015.
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c105780_2015_imo